# VBA: enum item interferes with Access Month() function

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am using `Access 2016` (standalone, without the rest of Office). I created an `enum` in which one item was `"Month = 5"`, as follows:

```
Enum E_TimeUnit
    Second = 1
    Minute = 2
    Day = 3
    Week = 4
    Month = 5
End Enum.
```

After that, the Access `Month()` function was no longer recognized by the IDE.  I changed the enum item from `"Month = 5"` to `"Months = 5"`, as follows:

```
Enum E_TimeUnit
    Seconds = 1
    Minutes = 2
    Days = 3
    Weeks = 4
    Months = 5
End Enum.
```

Now everything works again. But I have to wonder: Is this sort of interference normal, or is it an odd bug?

Answer (score 2):

It is normal and by design.

You can work around it by specifying *VBA* explicit:

```
 SomeMonth = VBA.Month(SomeDate)
```